# AS3 changing KeyboardEvents to MouseEvents

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm learning AS3 using Adobe Flash CS6, I'm working on a tutorial to create a moving object with animation using `KeyboardEvent`s and it works perfectly but now I want to change it so I can use buttons on the screen (`MouseEvent`s) to move the character but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
var movingRight;
var movingLeft;

function onKeyPress(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        movingRight=1;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        movingLeft=1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move your `character` using buttons you have to use two [`MouseEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html)s : a `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` event when a button is pressed and `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` when it's released, so you can do like this :

```
LeftBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, LeftBTN_onPress);
LeftBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, LeftBTN_onRelease);
function LeftBTN_onPress(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    movingLeft = 1;
}
function LeftBTN_onRelease(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    character.gotoAndStop(1);
    movingLeft = 0;
}

RightBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, RightBTN_onPress);
RightBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, RightBTN_onRelease);
function RightBTN_onPress(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    movingRight = 1;
}
function RightBTN_onRelease(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    character.gotoAndStop(4);
    movingRight = 0;
}
```

You can also use one function for all your event listeners like this :

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, move_character);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, move_character);
LeftBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, move_character);
LeftBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, move_character);
RightBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, move_character);
RightBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, move_character);

function move_character(e:*){

    var event_type:String = e.type;                     // get event type : to identify which kind of event is fired
    var current_target:String = e.currentTarget.name;   // get target name : to identify the target of the fired event

    switch (event_type){

        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN :

            if(current_target == 'LeftBTN') movingLeft = 1;
            else movingRight = 1;

            break;

        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP:

            if(current_target == 'LeftBTN'){
                character.gotoAndStop(1);
                movingLeft = 0;
            } else {
                character.gotoAndStop(4);
                movingRight = 0;
            }           
            break;      

        case KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN:

            if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){           
                movingRight = 1;            
            } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {            
                movingLeft = 1;         
            }           
            break;

        case KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP:

            if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {           
                character.gotoAndStop(1);
                movingLeft = 0;         
            } else if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {           
                character.gotoAndStop(4);
                movingRight = 0;            
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

OR, using the `e` parameter as an `Event` :

```
function move_character(e:Event){

    var event_type:String = e.type;                     // get event type : to identify which kind of event is fired
    var current_target:String = e.currentTarget.name;   // get target name : to identify the target of the fired event
    var key_code:Number;

    switch (event_type){

        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN :

            if(current_target == 'LeftBTN') movingLeft = 1;
            else movingRight = 1;

            break;

        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP:

            if(current_target == 'LeftBTN'){
                character.gotoAndStop(1);
                movingLeft = 0;
            } else {
                character.gotoAndStop(4);
                movingRight = 0;
            }           
            break;      

        case KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN:

            key_code = KeyboardEvent(e).keyCode;

            if (key_code == Keyboard.RIGHT){     
                movingRight = 1;            
            } else if (key_code == Keyboard.LEFT) {            
                movingLeft = 1;         
            }           
            break;

        case KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP:

            key_code = KeyboardEvent(e).keyCode;

            if (key_code == Keyboard.LEFT) {           
                character.gotoAndStop(1);
                movingLeft = 0;         
            } else if (key_code == Keyboard.RIGHT) {           
                character.gotoAndStop(4);
                movingRight = 0;            
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Voted down. The method as an untyped parameter which is bad practice. Since all event inherit from Event why in the world not typing the parameter as Event?

Comment: @BotMaster I agree with you, but I tried to do easy because OP is new in the world of AS3. I'll edit my answer to add that.

Answer (score 0):

Put two buttons on the stage, name them like btnRight and btnLeft, then use this code

```
btnLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick, false, 0, true);
btnRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick, false, 0, true);

function onButtonClick(evt:MouseEvent) {
    if (evt.target == btnLeft) movingLeft = 1;
    else movingRight = 1;
}
```

I would also suggest using only one var named movingDirection which can be 1, 0 or -1 :)